# Killing child and its children when child was created using open

Tags: perl, kill, children

Here's my code, with error handling and other stuff removed for clarity:

```
sub launch_and_monitor {  

    my ($script, $timeout) = @_;

    sub REAPER {
        while ((my $child = waitpid(-1, &WNOHANG)) > 0) {}
        $SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;
    }
    $SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;

    my $pid = fork;
    if (defined $pid) {
        if ($pid == 0) {
            # in child
            monitor($timeout);
        }
        else {
            launch($script);
        }
    }
}
```

The launch sub executes a shell script which in turn launches other processes, like so:

```
sub launch($) {

    my ($script) = @_;

    my $pid = open(PIPE, "$script|");

    # write pid to pidfile
    
    if ($pid != 0) {
        while(<PIPE>) {
            # do stuff with output
        }
        close(PIPE) or die $!;
    }
}
```

The monitor sub basically just waits for a specified period of time and then attempts to kill the shell script.

```
sub monitor($) {

    my ($timeout) = @_;

    sleep $timeout;

    # check if script is still running and if so get pid from pidfile
    if (...) {
        my $pid = getpid(...);        
        kill 9, $pid;
    }
}
```

This kills the script, however, it does not kill any of its subprocesses. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your main question, but I'd recommend making `REAPER` an anonymous sub, e.g. `my $reaper = sub { ... }; $SIG{CHLD} = $reaper;` Putting a named sub inside another sub doesn't hide it from other scopes. All named subs are package symbols in Perl

Comment: http://www.speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html

Comment: good point, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with process groups, if your operating system supports them. You need to make the script process become a process group leader. The child processes that it runs will inherit the process group from their parent. You can then use kill to send a signal to each process in the group at the same time.

In `launch()`, you will need to replace the `open` line with one that forks. Then in the child, you would call `setpgrp()` before exec'ing the command. Something like the following should work:

```
my $pid = open(PIPE, "-|");
if (0 == $pid) {
    setpgrp(0, 0);
    exec $script;
    die "exec failed: $!\n";
}
else {
    while(<PIPE>) {
        # do stuff with output
    }
    close(PIPE) or die $!;
}
```

Later, to kill the script process and its children, negate the process ID that you're signalling:

```
kill 9, -$pid;
```

Comment: I think you should negate the signal number (or name) not the PID: `kill '-9', $pid`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I don't think you can expect signals to be propagated into all child processes; this isn't specific to perl.

That said, you might be able to use the process *group* signal feature built into perl [kill()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html):

> ...if SIGNAL is negative, it kills process groups instead of processes...

You probably need to use [setpgrp()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/setpgrp.html) on your (direct) child process, then change your kill call to something like:

```
kill -9, $pgrp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
use POSIX qw(setsid);
setsid;
```

at the top of your `launch_and_monitor` function.  This will put your processes in a separate session, and cause things to exit when the session leader (i.e. the master) exits.

Answer (score 1):

Killing a processgroup works, but don't forget the parent can be killed alone too. Assuming child processes have an event loop, they can check the parent socket that was created in a socketpair prior doing the fork() for validness. In fact, select() cleanly exits when the parent socket is gone, all that needs to be done is to check the socket.

E.g.:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Socket;

$SIG{CHLD} = sub {};

socketpair(my $p, my $c, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC) or die $!;

print "parent $$, fork 2 kids\n";
for (0..1){
    my $kid = fork();
    unless($kid){
        child_loop($p, $c);
        exit; 
    }
    print "parent $$, forked kid $kid\n";
}

print "parent $$, waiting 5s\n";
sleep 5;
print "parent $$ exit, closing sockets\n";

sub child_loop {
    my ($p_s, $c_s) = @_;
    print "kid: $$\n";
    close($c_s);
    my $rin = '';
    vec($rin, fileno($p_s), 1) = 1;
    while(1){
        select my $rout = $rin, undef, undef, undef;
        if(vec($rout, fileno($p_s), 1)){
            print "kid: $$, parent gone, exiting\n";
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

Runs like this:

```
tim@mint:~$ perl ~/abc.pl
parent 5638, fork 2 kids
parent 5638, forked kid 5639
kid: 5639
parent 5638, forked kid 5640
parent 5638, waiting 5s
kid: 5640
parent 5638 exit, closing sockets
kid: 5640, parent gone, exiting
kid: 5639, parent gone, exiting
tim@mint:~$
```