# How can I timeout a forked process that might hang?

Tags: perl, fork, alarm

I am writing a Perl script that will write some inputs and send those inputs to an external program. There is a small but non-zero chance that this program will hang, and I want to time it out:

```
my $pid = fork;
if ($pid > 0){
    eval{
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "TIMEOUT!"};
        alarm $num_secs_to_timeout;
        waitpid($pid, 0);
        alarm 0;
    };
}
elsif ($pid == 0){
    exec('echo blahblah | program_of_interest');
    exit(0);
}
```

As it stands now, after $num_secs_to_timeout, program_of_interest still persists. I tried to kill it in the anonymous subroutine for `$SIG{ALRM}` as follows:

```
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub{kill 9, $pid; die "TIMEOUT!"}
```

but this doesn't do anything. program_of_interest is still persisting. How do I go about killing this process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to successfully kill my exec()ed process by **killing the process group**, as shown as the answer to question [In perl, killing child and its children when child was created using open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675750/in-perl-killing-child-and-its-children-when-child-was-created-using-open/1675968#1675968). I modified my code as follows:

```
my $pid = fork;
if ($pid > 0){
    eval{
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {kill 9, -$PID; die "TIMEOUT!"};
        alarm $num_secs_to_timeout;
        waitpid($pid, 0);
        alarm 0;
    };
}
elsif ($pid == 0){
    setpgrp(0,0);
    exec('echo blahblah | program_of_interest');
    exit(0);
}
```

After timeout, program_of_interest is successfully killed.

Comment: I think "kill 9, -$PID" should be "kill -9, $PID". I used system("kill -9 $PID") instead.

Comment: I think "kill -9 $PID" should further be "kill -9 $pid", but yes, the negative pid indicates to kill a process group instead of just a process. From the kill documentation: "Unlike in the shell, if SIGNAL is negative, it kills process groups instead of processes. (On System V, a negative PROCESS number will also kill process groups, but that's not portable.)"

Answer (score 3):

The above code (by strictlyrude27) didn't work out of the box, because -$PID is spelt in capitals.
(BTW: there's also: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html)

Here's an example with test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $prg = basename $0;
my $num_secs_sleep = 2;
my $num_secs_to_timeout = 1;
my $orig_program = "sleep $num_secs_sleep; echo \"Look ma, survived!\"";
my $program = $orig_program;
my $expect = "";

if (@ARGV){
  if($ARGV[0] eq "test"){
    test();
    exit 0;
  } elsif (@ARGV == 1) {
    $num_secs_to_timeout = $ARGV[0];
  } elsif (@ARGV == 2) {
    $program = $ARGV[0];
    $num_secs_to_timeout = $ARGV[1];
  } else {
    die "Usage: $prg [ \"test\" | [program] seconds ] "
  }
}

if($orig_program eq $program) {
  if(@ARGV < 2) {
    $expect = $num_secs_to_timeout > $num_secs_sleep ?
      "(we expected to survive.)" : "(we expected to TIME OUT!)";
  }
  print STDERR "sleeping: $num_secs_sleep seconds$/";
}

print STDERR <<END;
  timeout after: $num_secs_to_timeout seconds,
  running program: '$program'
END

if($orig_program eq $program) {
  print STDERR "$expect$/";
}

exit Timed::timed($program, $num_secs_to_timeout);

sub test {
  eval "use Test::More qw(no_plan);";
  my $stdout;
  close STDOUT;
  open STDOUT, '>', \$stdout or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";
  Timed::timed("sleep 1", 3);
  is($stdout, undef);
  Timed::timed("sleep 2", 1);
  is($stdout, "TIME OUT!$/");
}

################################################################################
package Timed;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub timed {
  my $retval;
  my ($program, $num_secs_to_timeout) = @_;
  my $pid = fork;
  if ($pid > 0){ # parent process
    eval{
      local $SIG{ALRM} = 
        sub {kill 9, -$pid; print STDOUT "TIME OUT!$/"; $retval = 124;};
      alarm $num_secs_to_timeout;
      waitpid($pid, 0);
      alarm 0;
    };
    return defined($retval) ? $retval : $?>>8;
  }
  elsif ($pid == 0){ # child process
    setpgrp(0,0);
    exec($program);
  } else { # forking not successful
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm **your code works for me**, after some minor modifications - which I assume are changes made by yourself to make the code into a generic example.

So that leaves me with two ideas:

1. **You removed the problem when you created the sample code** - try creating a small sample that actually runs (I had to change 'program_of_interest' and $num_secs_to_timeout to real values to test it). Make sure the sample has the same problem.
2. **It's something to do with the program_of_interest you're running** - as far as I know, you can't mask a kill 9, but maybe there's something going on. Have you tried testing your code with a really simple script. I created one for my testing that goes while (1) { print "hi\n"; sleep 1; }
3. **Something else**.

Good luck...

Comment: Looks like you were right: I actually piped something into program_of_interest: system("echo blahblah | program_of_interest"). sh was being exec'd and properly killed, but not program_of_interest..

Answer (score 1):

The only way SIGKILL can be ignored is if the process is stuck in a system call which is uninterruptible. Check the state of the hung process (with `ps aux`) if the state is D, then the process can't be killed.

You might also want to check that the function is being called by outputting something from it.