# How to check if command executed with IPC::open3 is hung?

Tags: perl, ipc

I'm using the following script to capture `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` from the command passed as an argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open3;

local(*CMD_IN, *CMD_OUT, *CMD_ERR);

my $pid = open3(*CMD_IN, *CMD_OUT, *CMD_ERR, $ARGV[0]); 

close(CMD_IN);

my @stdout_output = <CMD_OUT>;
my @stderr_output = <CMD_ERR>; 

close(CMD_OUT);
close(CMD_ERR);

waitpid ($pid, 0); # reap the exit code

print "OUT:\n", @stdout_output;
print "ERR:\n", @stderr_output;
```

It all works good with the exception that I'm not sure how to monitor if the command passed is hung. Could you please suggest a way?

I've borrowed this snippet originally from 'Programming Perl'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `select` or `IO::Select` and provide a timeout. If you want to read both from stdout and stderr, you should do that anyway (see the documentation of `IPC::Open3`).

Here's an example program using `IO::Select`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Select;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';

my ($cmd_in, $cmd_out, $cmd_err);
$cmd_err = gensym;
my $pid = open3($cmd_in, $cmd_out, $cmd_err, $ARGV[0]);

close($cmd_in);

my $select = IO::Select->new($cmd_out, $cmd_err);
my $stdout_output = '';
my $stderr_output = '';

while (my @ready = $select->can_read(5)) {
    foreach my $handle (@ready) {
        if (sysread($handle, my $buf, 4096)) {
            if ($handle == $cmd_out) {
                $stdout_output .= $buf;
            }
            else {
                $stderr_output .= $buf;
            }
        }
        else {
            # EOF or error
            $select->remove($handle);
        }
    }
}

if ($select->count) {
    print "Timed out\n";
    kill('TERM', $pid);
}

close($cmd_out);
close($cmd_err);

waitpid($pid, 0); # reap the exit code

print "OUT:\n", $stdout_output;
print "ERR:\n", $stderr_output;
```

Notes:

- I use lexical vars for file handles. This requires the use of `gensym` for the stderr handle.
- The argument to `can_read` is the timeout in seconds.
- I use `sysread` for non-buffered IO.
- I terminate the child if there's a read timeout.

Comment: Thanks very much! I actually implemented something that does the job, but I'd rather avoid using signals and use your solution instead. I will post it anyway if someone else is interested.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution heavily based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962985/how-can-i-timeout-a-forked-process-that-might-hang) answer.

However using `select` and avoiding signals as in nwellnhof's example looks much cleaner which is why I accepted it. I'm posting it here if somebody is interested:

```
my $pid = open3(*CMD_IN, *CMD_OUT, *CMD_ERR, $cmd);

if ($pid > 0){
    eval{
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {kill 9, $pid;};
        alarm 6;
        waitpid($pid, 0);
        alarm 0;
    };
}
```